# ios image size in memory doesn't match with what's on disk

Tags: ios, image, memory

I have a simple image view and i load a 99 kb file on to it. However, once the image view is rendered, and when i observe the memory consumption in the "debug navigator" (xcode) it's showing up as 12 MB. I mean, without the image being rendered, with just the view controller on screen and an empty image view, memory consumed is 2 MB. With the 99 kb image loaded the memory consumption jumps to 14 MB.

Why is this discrepancy and what am i missing here ? a 99KB image loaded onto memory is showing up as 12 MB from a consumption stand point.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Image files store compressed image data. But `UIImage` in memory stores color information of every pixel. Therefore the `UIImage` can be much larger then the image file on disk.

Often `UIImage` memory usage can be counted like this.

> pixelCount * 4 byte (red, green, blue, alpha)